# Komodo Edit - How to disable the 'Linter' for a language?

Tags: text-editors, ide, komodo-edit

I've been using Komodo Edit to work on a Django project.

It works great except for one little annoyance:  When I am editing Django template files, Komodo likes to put red squiggly lines underneath the first HTML tag that follows a Django tag, because it thinks it is an invalid HTML doc (although it isn't, it just has Django template tags/filters in it).

Note that this red squiggly line is called a "Linter error" in the docs that I can find.

Is there some way to turn off this red squiggly for only a specific type of language?  It's nice to have when working on Python code but it's annoying to have a red squiggly on every single one of my Django templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get a [response with a workaround](http://community.activestate.com/forum/linter-errors-when-editing-django-templates) for this on the ActiveState forums:

I needed to go to

```
<komodo_dir>/lib/mozilla/extensions/django_language@ActiveState.com/components/
```

and edit `koDjango_UDL_Language.py`.

Adding the following method to the class turns off the linter for django files only:

```
def get_linter(self):
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

You might ask on one of Activestate's KOMODO mail lists. The devs read it, so you'll most likely get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the style under preferences to be 'hidden'.
Edit->Preferences->Fonts and Colors->Indicators (tab)-> Style: (look for Hidden).